# ESC light on and erratic acceleration

Tags: troubleshooting, chrysler, electronic-stability-control, 200

I have recently bought my 2013 Chrysler 200 and recently changed my brakes and oil on my own for the first time on this car.

A couple days later my ESC light came on on the highway and it felt like the car was dragging a little and when I would reach a certain speed the and press on the gas it wouldn’t accelerate like normal at all. Plus when I would come to a stop it sometimes would jerk quite a bit.

I’m thinking it’s a position throttle body sensor or maybe a transmission problem., but I thought I’d get other people opinions on it.

Comment: Why did the light come on? What were the codes? Can you provide a datalog of the major PIDs?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!